# Execute CURL command inside Angular Test

Tags: typescript, phantomjs, karma-jasmine

I need to run a simple shell command on OS level inside an angular service test which is running headless on phantomjs.

It is needed because of testing CORS functionality (which is ignored by CMD in order to verify the test).

I read about child_process, but it is a node functionality. How can I exec a shell command inside my Jasmine Typescript???

Comment: Karma tests run inside the browser.  You cannot execute a shell command from inside the browser.  What exactly are you trying to test?  CORS should be a non-issue for an Angular application as the browser should handle CORS for you.  CORS is usually only something you need to worry about on a server.  If you are testing server code then you should be using some kind of testing framework other than karma.

Comment: Understand that. I would like to test with data, which comes from a source where such requests are forbidden by cors... is there a possibility to execute a shell command before phantomjs or other processes start and pass the result as parameter?

Comment: If you’re testing interactions with external servers then maybe protractor would be a better fit.  Can you add HTTP APIs on the other servers to do whatever you need done on them?

Comment: Ok, lets assume I would like to inject a password and a username only for testing purposes... How would I do that? How can I pass those parameters as Arguments into ng test and followed by karma and phantomjs?

Comment: One way would be to create a `prepare-testbed.js` script and, in your `package.json` file you can change the `test` script from `ng test` to `node scripts/prepare-testbed.js && ng test`.  Then you will also need to run `npm run test` instead of `ng test`.  The script `prepare-testbed.js` will run inside of node and have access to running shell commands, ssh, etc.

Comment: If you just need to get the test username/password into your karma tests then you can use `client.args` in your [Karma configuration file](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/config/configuration-file.html)